# Shell script to delete a line next to empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm able to delete empty lines from a file using `grep` or `sed`. But, I'm unable to resolve a scenario where I have to delete a valid line next to empty lines. Following is an example:

Source:

```
1_1
1_2
1_3
1
2_1
2_2
2_3
2_4
2_5
2

3
4_1
4_2
4
5_1
5_2
5_3
5_4
5



6
7_1
7
8_1
8_2
8
```

Output:

```
1_1
1_2
1_3
1
2_1
2_2
2_3
2_4
2_5
2
4_1
4_2
4
5_1
5_2
5_3
5_4
5
7_1
7
8_1
8_2
8
```

How to delete the valid line next to empty lines?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear: what is a "valid line" that you want to delete ? Try to provide a smaller example that shows in addition to that - the "expected output".

Comment: "valid line" refers to the line which is not empty.

Comment: a "valid line" before or after an empty space (or both) ? "next to" is not a good definition...

Comment: "after". Please refer to the example provided with the question. Solution provided by @SMA works like a champ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
sed '/^$/,+1 d' test.txt
```

whenever you find an empty line, delete it and next immediate line.

Comment: It works fine! Just for curiousity, can it be done by "grep" ?

Comment: You say you want to `delete a valid line next to empty lines` and that `"valid line" refers to the line which is not empty.` so - note that unlike @Jotne's posted awk solution the above sed script will NOT delete a valid line after 2 (or any other even number of) consecutive empty lines. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk`solution:

```
awk '!NF {f=1;next} f {f=0;next}1' file
1_1
1_2
1_3
1
2_1
2_2
2_3
2_4
2_5
2
4_1
4_2
4
5_1
5_2
5_3
5_4
5
7_1
7
8_1
8_2
8
```

`!NF {f=1;next}` if line is blank, set `f=1` and skip the line.
Then if line is not blank, test if `f` is true.
`{f=0;next}` if its true, set `f=0` and skip the line.
`1` print the remaining line.

---

And some gofling done by ED

```
awk 'NF&&!f;{f=!NF}' file
```

Comment: 'Nother awk `awk 'f&&NF;{f=NF}'`

Comment: `grep` is a tool to `Globally find a Regular Expression and Print the result` (note what the capital letters spell out). It is not a tool to `look for blank lines and lines around them and remove them` so even if you could somehow cobble together some combination of grep args to make it produce the output you want (and the GNU guys have certainly butchered it enough that that might be do-able), it will always be a worse choice than awk which was designed for general text processing like this.

Comment: @JID and Jotne - `awk 'f&&NF;{f=NF}' file` would skip printing the first line since `f` is not set. FWIW I'd use `awk 'NF&&!f;{f=!NF}'` for golf (but not for readability!).

Comment: @EdMorton I really need to start checking code before posting! Apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^$/ {
:a
   N
   /\n$/ ba
   d
   }' YourFile
```

- Posix version
- remove ALL continuous empty line and next (non empty) one

Comment: not sure due to reference on next/previous line. Remove empty line is no problem but not the line following empty line. Maybe with a `-p` perl regex on GNU version (not the `-p` from posix that specify the paragraph separator and remove it)